# prop('disabled', false); is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, prop

I want to make a button that will be disable when checkbox is false. But `prop('disabled', false);` isn't working.

```js
$(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if ($('#аgree').prop(':checked')) {
            $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#button').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text-center">З правилами анкетування ознайомлений(а) і згоден(на) @Html.CheckBox("Agree", false, new { id = "agree" }) </p>
<p class="text-center"><input type="button" id="button" disabled="disabled" value="Пройти анкетування" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Form")'" /></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `this` refers to the DOM.

Change it to

```
$("#agree").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the element that triggered the change event.

or simply:

```
$("#agree").click(function() {
    $('#button').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: $("#agree").click(function() {
    $('#button').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});

It`s right. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the attribute.

```
$('#button').removeAttr('disabled')
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem as OP but this solution worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the checkbox is checked with `.is(":checked")`,
also, listen to a change event on the checkbox itself.

Below is a little modified code (to make it work here)

```js
$(function() {
    $('#agree').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#button').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text-center">З правилами анкетування ознайомлений(а) і згоден(на) <input type=checkbox id=agree> </p>
<p class="text-center"><input type="button" id="button" disabled="disabled" value="Пройти анкетування" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Form")'" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable button, you can use:

```
$('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To make button active, you can use:

```
$('#button').attr('disabled', '');
```